# Dynamic object property names?

Tags: javascript, json, variables

How can I make this happen:

```
var name = otherObject.name; //"string"
var o = { 
            name : otherObject
        };
alert(o["string"].name);
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use bracket notation instead.

```
var name = otherObject.name;
var o = {};
o[name] = otherObject;
```

Or, in modern JavaScript:

```
var o = {
  [name]: otherObject,
};
```

Comment: Since this is a decent duplicate target, it might be helpful to be more specific than "modern JavaScript". This syntax was introduced in ECMAScript 2015, and is called a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015). Here's the link to the specification's [`ComputedPropertyName` expression](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-ComputedPropertyName) in case you want to cite the specification directly as well.