# Evaluate a variable to use as a variable name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript Objects: Dynamic variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798446/javascript-objects-dynamic-variable-names)

I have a json string passed in from a cgi script. This json string has a list of id's. In javascript

```
var informationObj = jQuery.parseJSON(information);
tid = informationObj.idList[0].id;
```

tid is now an ID and I want to use it to access objects within the json string itself like so:

```
alert (informationObj.tid.rpath);
```

However this does not seem to work. I have also tried:

```
alert (informationObj.eval(tid).rpath);
```

Is there a way around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this form:

```
informationObj[tid].rpath
```

They are equivalent:

```
var a = 'something';
b[a] === b.something
```

Answer (score 2):

Use bracket notation:

```
alert(informationObj[tid].rpath);
```