# How to use a variable in JavaScript command?

Tags: eval, javascript

Consider a simple JS function as

```
function test(property, color) {
    var element = document.getElementById("test");
    element.style.PROPERTY = color; // I want to use a variable for this command
}
```

In a typical JS command of `element.style.PROPERTY`, I want to introduce the property as a variable. This is a very basic example; what is the best approach to use variables in JS command lines?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Objects: Dynamic variable names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798446/javascript-objects-dynamic-variable-names)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it as:

```
element.style[property]
```

> This is a very basic example; what is the best approach to use variables in JS command lines?

It depends on what you want to achieve. In this case - just use `[...]`

Comment: And, of course, `.replace(/-(.)/g, function(a, b) { return b.toUpperCase(); })` for all those quirky hyphenated properties! And then, `cssFloat`. And then, `-ms` prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

`element.style[property] = color;` should work.