# How to assign a function variable's value as a variable name within a Javascript function

Tags: javascript

i have dynamic data thats coming into my application, the data structure is the same but the name of the property name being reported on changes. I am trying to write a function that would accept the value of the property variable input to a function and assign it as a variable name.

In the code below, for the measurements variable I want the variable name 'tag' to be the value of the 'tagName' input for the fucntion. 
Appreciate any help i can get with this! Thankyou!

```
function iotcjson(device, tagName, value) {

  var data = {
    device: { deviceId: device },
    measurements: { tag: value }
  }

  return data
}
```

Considering value of `tagName` is "temperature"

Actual result:

```
{"device":{"deviceId":"device1"},"measurements"{"tag":11.2}}
```

Desired Result:

```
{"device":{"deviceId":"device1"},"measurements"{"temperature":11.2}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic object property names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798446/dynamic-object-property-names) and [Creating object with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837916)

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_name) for the wanted result.

For `device`, you could take the later property name directly of `deviceId` and insert this variable as [short hand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```js
function iotcjson(deviceId, tagName, value) {
   var data = {
       device: { deviceId },
       measurements: { [tagName]: value }
    };
    return data;
}

console.log(iotcjson('device1', 'temperature', 11.2));
```