# What is the meaning of the following syntax: [increment]: () => {}?

Tags: javascript, redux, syntax, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Here is the code snippet I am trying to understand.

```
import { increment } from '../features/counter/counterSlice'
const object = {
  [increment]: () => {}
}
console.log(object)
// logs { "counter/increment": Function}
```

Specifically what does the following syntax do?

`[increment]: () => {}`

Increment is a reducer function created by createSlice().

Comment: creates an arrow function, named whatever the value of variable increment is, on `object`

Comment: That syntax only does anything because it is inside an object.

Comment: actually, `increment` is not *a reducer function*, it's a `string`

Comment: @QuentinUK - much like a lot of syntax, validity does depend on context

Comment: [How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2274242) | [Dynamic object property names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1798446) | [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1184123) | [Add a property to a JavaScript object using a variable as the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/695050)

Comment: @Bravo - Yes your right. ```increment``` is a string. Thanks.

Comment: @Bravo I'm reminded of "What is the “-->” operator in C/C++?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
const object = {
  [increment]: () => {}
}
```

is identical in result to

```
const object = {};
object[increment] = () => {};
```

In other words creates an arrow function, named whatever the value of variable increment is, on `object`

Answer (score 2):

```
const object = {
  [increment]: () => {}
}
```

This creates an object that has one property. The name of that property is defined by the string in the variable named `increment`. If `increment` had a value of `"foo"` then this would be equivalent to:

```
const object = {
  foo: () => {}
}
```

The value of that property is a function that does nothing.

An arrow function has this form

```
(...args) => { /* function body */ }
```

So `() => {}` is a function that takes no arguments, and has no statements in its function body.