# Angular router navigate set query parameter name from variable

Tags: angular, routes

I would like to set the query parameter name dynamically.

`this.router.navigate([alternativeRedirect],{ queryParams: { supportContractId: p },})`

Is it possible to set supportContractId dynamically:

`let parameterName = 'supportContractId'`

`this.router.navigate([alternativeRedirect],{ queryParams: { parameterName: p },})`

Comment: If I have understood your question right, you basically want to create `queryParams` object with dynamic keys?

Comment: Have you already tried [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1798476/8941307) (second option)

Answer (score 2):

You can define the params object beforehand and set the properties dynamically using the [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) (aka bracket notation). It would be something along those lines:

```
let params = {};
params[parameterName] = p;
this.router.navigate([alternativeRedirect],{ queryParams: params})
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the ECMAScript2015 language specification, you can create objects with computed keys.

Therefore you can directly do the following,

```
let parameterName = 'supportContractID'
this.router.navigate([alternativeRedirect],{ queryParams: { [parameterName]: value })
```