# How to split an array of strings & return a single object with key/value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, functional-programming

I have this `array` of `strings`:

```js
[ 
  'Back to Main Window: Retour à la fenêtre principale',
  'All Client Groups: Tous les groupes de clients',
  'Filter by Client: Filtrer par client' 
]
```

I would like to transform it into an `object` with `key/value` pairs like so:

```js
{
   'Back to Main Window': 'Retour à la fenêtre principale',
   'All Client Groups': 'Tous les groupes de clients',
   'Filter by Client': 'Filtrer par client' 
}
```

I have to tried to use `map()` & `split()`, but I get this output instead:

```js
const results = translations.map(translation => {
  const [key, value] = translation.split(':');

  return { key: value };
});

// results returns an "array" with the "key" word as key for all values :(
// [ { key: ' Retour à la fenêtre principale' },
//   { key: ' Tous les groupes de clients' },
//   { key: ' Filtrer par client' } ]
//
```

Comment: All you needed was to use a [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015) name in your return: `return {[key]: value};`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic object property names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798446/dynamic-object-property-names)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array and [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) each item by `': '`, then use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
const arr = [ 
  'Back to Main Window: Retour à la fenêtre principale',
  'All Client Groups: Tous les groupes de clients',
  'Filter by Client: Filtrer par client' 
]


const res = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(e => e.split(": ")))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: For anyone who wants an array of arrays instead of an object, just remove the `Object.fromEntries` part.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to @Spectric would be to use `reduce`, to transform your array to an object.

```js
const arr = [ 
  'Back to Main Window: Retour à la fenêtre principale',
  'All Client Groups: Tous les groupes de clients',
  'Filter by Client: Filtrer par client' 
];

function transform(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((obj, line) => {
    const [key, value] = line.split(': ');
    obj[key] = value;
    return obj;
  }, {});
}

console.log(transform(arr));
```